# SAS: string replacement using reference value

Tags: string, replace, sas

I have a dataset with one id column and three character variables:

```
data have;
    input id var1 $ var2 $ var3 $;
    datalines;
    1 * 1.2 *
    2 * 3.7 0.3
    3 0.7 * 2
    4 4.9 4.0 1.8
    ;
run;
```

For each of the character variable, I want to replace the '*' character with a string that is specific to the variable.
For example, in var1 '*' would be replace by '2', then in var2 '*' would be replaced by '4.5', etc...
And then I would like to turn these variables to numeric.
Is there a way of doing this using a "reference" table with the replacement values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to store the replacement values for the `*` inputs.  You will need to use the `INPUT()` function to convert the character value to a numeric value.  Note: SAS DATA Step is not like scripting languages that allow variables to change 'types' on the fly at run-time.

Example:

Each arrayed character variable is converted to a numeric value saved in a separate variable.  `rename=` is used in the output data set options to change the name of the numeric variables back to the original corresponding names.

```
data want(rename=(num1-num3=var1-var3)) ;
  set have ;
  array char var1-var3 ;
  array num  num1-num3 ; 
  array r [3] _temporary_ (2, 4.5, 13) ;
  do over char ;
    if char = '*' then num = r[_i_]; else num = input(char, best.);
  end ;
  drop var1-var3;
run ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably simplest to just replace any invalid string with the default value (not just the ones that are exactly '*').

```
data want;
  set have;
  array old var1-var3 ;
  array new num1-num3 ;
  array default [3] _temporary_ (2 4.5 77) ;
  do index= 1 to dim(old);
    new[index]=coalesce(input(old[index],??32.),default[index]);
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    id    var1    var2    var3    num1    num2    num3

 1      1    *       1.2     *        2.0     1.2    77.0
 2      2    *       3.7     0.3      2.0     3.7     0.3
 3      3    0.7     *       2        0.7     4.5     2.0
 4      4    4.9     4.0     1.8      4.9     4.0     1.8
```